# Is passing text directly from user to `java.util.regex.Pattern` safe?

Tags: java, regex

Is passing user input directly to `java.util.regex.Pattern` which is later used by `java.util.regex.Matcher` safe?

If not, why? Does it create infinite loop or exponential calculation? If so, what are the other options?

Comment: One can craft a regex that will consume a lot  of CPU time. As a matter of fact SO went [down](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016.) once because of that. So if that regexp runs on a server you should sanitize it. If it runs on the client's machine it should be no problem

Comment: @litelite what are sanitizing options?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/redos-attacks-python-application-architectures-akshat-mahajan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regexp` is never safe. Personally, I refrain from using them If I don't really have to. Somebody can construct a Regexp that will take ages to be checked or will ever crash the system.

Some additional reading can be found here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

I can't think of a use-case that would justify letting user pass the regex to your server.

Comment: well it is for search (& replace), seems like regex option is good, though

Comment: @Enerccio Are your end users programmers?  If not, they probably don’t need the power of regular expressions.  You’d be better off letting them enter simplified glob patterns, where `*` and `?` are the only special metacharacters;  such a string is easy to translate internally into a regex.

Comment: @Pijotrek I did, so only problem is DoS, which can easily be fixed by imposing the time limit on the regex. Thanks!